# How to grant elevated privileges to a specific assembly, on an entire domain

Tags: .net, windows, security

I have a situation where I need to deploy an assembly to every PC on my domain.  The majority of users do not have Admin access on their machines.

My assembly will be run by the domain users, but will also require Admin privileges.  What is the best approach for that?

I've read the guidelines for .Net 1.1 and 2.0, which seem to recommend using `caspol.exe` to grant privileges based on the location of the assembly.  This does not seem clean.

Are there more modern approaches available?

I was expecting I'd be able to give my assembly a Strong Name then use a Group Policy to fully trust that assembly and grant it elevated privileges automatically.

Thanks for you help.

PS.  We are using .Net 4.0.

Comment: Code Access Security affects what code can do with permissions that the user account it's running under can already do. There's no concept of letting some code run under higher privileges than the user already holds.

Comment: So what you're saying is that `caspol.exe` isn't a solution at all?

Comment: Correct. The only way that a (non-admin) user can run code, some of which requires Admin privileges, is for it to have a manifest that forces UAC to occur - and at the point that UAC happens, they need to be able to provide the username/password for an admin user. I'd separate your code into code that the non-admins run and then a separate service that runs under admin privileges - then use any standard way (e.g. WCF, TCP, etc) for one to contact the other and ask for Admin tasks to be performed. Whether you install that service on each machine or on a central server is an arch decision.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly the approach I started considering after your first post.  And it just so happens that our assembly could easily be divided into two logical halves.  One an admin-level service, and the other containing all the other logic.